# Only remove white space which precedes a specific character. with libre office regex engine

Tags: regex, replace, sed, find, libreoffice

I'm attempting to perform this in Libre Office's regex engine and sed in ubuntu terminal.

1.Example strings:

```
-Polizeiwache (f)police station
-Freibad (n)open-air swimming pool
```

2.Desired outputs:

```
-Polizeiwache (f)policestation
-Freibad (n)open-airswimmingpool
```

I've been trying to select the character `)` and replace every succeeding space with nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is unclear.  Your text says "replace every", but your example shows replacing only the first space.  To replace every:

```
sed 'h;s/[^)]*//;s/ //g;x;s/).*//;G;s/\n//'
```

What this does:

- `h`  copy the line to sed's hold space
- `s/[^)]*//` replace not-a-) repeated with nothing.  This deletes the first part of the line.
- `s/ //g`  replace a blank with nothing.  `g` option says do for every occurrence.  Now we have the second part of the line as we want it.
- `x`  exchange hold space and pattern (working) space.  Now we have the whole line in the pattern space again.
- `s/).*//`  replace ) followed by any character sequence with nothing.  Now we have the first part of the line.
- `G`  append the hold space.  Now we have re-joined the whole line (second part edited), separated by a newline.
- `s/\n//`  remove the newline in the middle.

Comment: Thank you.
Could you explain the sequence of regex commands to me if possible, I would like to learn a bit more, because regex is a powerful tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\()[^ ]*\) /\1/g' yourfile
```

Pattern details:

```
\(      # open the capture group 1
)       # a literal closing parenthesis
[^ ]*   # zero or more (*) characters that are not a space [^ ] 
\)      # close the capture group 1
        # a space (do you see it?)
```

`\1` is a backreference to the capture group 1, in clear it contains all that has been matched in this group. Since the space is not in the group, it is removed.

`g` stands for *global research*

Comment: It's almost perfect, but I keep getting some lines like this: `Ampel (f$1light`
where they used to be like:`Ampel (f)traffic light`

Comment: @timi95: change `$1` to `\1`

Comment: It works!
Thank you, I'm new to regex.
Would you mind giving me an explanatory break down of this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F\) '{gsub(/ /,"",$NF)}1' OFS=\) file
-Polizeiwache (f)policestation
-Freibad (n)open-airswimmingpool
```

It sets `)` as filed separator, and then removes space from last field.

---

Or if you like to change only first space, use `sub` instead of `gsub`:

```
awk -F\) '{sub(/ /,"",$NF)}1' OFS=\) file
-Polizeiwache (f)policestation
-Freibad (n)open-airswimming pool
```